# rounding up value of file gotten from $_FILES[size] in php

Tags: php

I need to round up sizes of file uploaded and determine what size format whether it's kb,mb or gb.

Detail:
While users upload picture, picture attributes are fetched via the global $_FILES. If for example, a user upload a picture of 29.6kb, and I decide to check the size of the picture uploaded, the $_FILES[size] array echo the size as 30358.

And what I'm trying to do with the value gotten from the $_FILES[size] is to round up the picture size from 30758 to 31 and then concatenate the file size format (kb, mb or gb) to it and echo it as 31kb.

I really hope to get help with this...Thanks!

Comment: You should provide what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel](http://laravel.com/) uses this helper function:

```
function get_file_size($size)
{
  $units = array('Bytes', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB');
  return @round($size / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2).' '.$units[$i];
}
```

***Source**: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/helpers.php

I haven't seen a more elegant way for doing this yet.

Answer (score 0):

What's about that?

```
$file =  $_FILES[size];
$s = 'kb';
$x = round($file/1000, 1);
if($x > 1000){ 
    $x = $x/1000;
    $s = 'mb';
} else if($x > 100000) {
    $x = $x/100000;
    $s = 'gb';
}
echo $x . ' ' . $s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the php command round(float) and some simple maths:

```
define("K",1024);
define("M",1048576);
define("G",1073741824);

$size = $_FILES[size];
$gigs = $size / G;
$megs = ($size - ($gigs * G)) / M;
$kils = ($size - ($gigs * G) - ($megs * M)) / K;

if($gigs > 0) echo(round($gigs));
elseif($megs > 0) echo(round($megs));
elseif($kils > 0) echo(round($kils));
else echo("Size is zero");
```